# 'implicit' variable declaration in arrow functions/promises (and beyond)?

Tags: javascript, arrow-functions

```
fetch('/users')
  // .then(res => res.json()) 
  .then(res => res.text())         
  .then(text => console.log(text))
```

In the last line, the variable `text` appears out of thin air. Can I name that variable whatever I want and the program would still know what it represents? Does the program know what it represents because only one thing is returned and it goes through the thens like a hamster through a tube so it doesn't matter what you name it?

I had been wondering about this before and today I saw this again in the code above so I decided to ask.

Comment: It doesn't matter what you name it. `param => param + 1` is a (mostly) a shorthand for `function(param) { return param + 1}` You can name the parameter anything, it won't have an influence on how the code works the same way you can have a `var myVariable = 1` or `var counter = 1` - in both cases it's just a variable. If you do `myVariable + 1` or `counter + 1` the effects will be identical.

Comment: The variable appears out of the same air as every variable that you declared yourself, as a function parameter or not.

Comment: Where do you think the parameter name `res` comes from, and why do you believe there's a difference to the parameter name `text` in the other line?

Comment: ```res``` comes from somewhere deeper inside Express. I thought it was different from ```text``` because I'm pretty sure text doesn't come from somewhere deeper in Express

Comment: No, `res` is just an ordinary parameter variable. It's just a convention that everyone calls it `res`.